# Setting app icon on home(main) screen default

Tags: android, screen, settings, smsmanager, mainscreen

i'm working on an sms management application, it works instead of native android sms manager but i want to show my app on home(main) -i mean 1st screen-programatically.My application now seems on 6th screen and diffullt to reach to write a message.How can i put my app on home(main) screen?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to move the app starter to the desired place. Moving an app starter can be done with long click on the app starter icon and then move it to the right place.

If a new android application is installed it automatically places it to the end of the app list on your phone. You have to move it then manually...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Lorenz, you cannot force your application to specific place in application list.

But you can add a shortcut to Home Screen whenever you launch the application, so that application is always accessible from HOME.

Try [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-install-uninstall-shortcut-example/) for adding shortcut.